# What's the meaning of "slip" in this context (slip in his hands)?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Automatically, it seemed, Dumbledore reached out a long hand and seized the parchment. He held it out and stared at the name written upon it. There was a long pause, during which Dumbledore stared at the **slip** in his hands, and everyone in the room stared at Dumbledore.
>
> *Harry potter and the Goblet of fire*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slip is the paper parchment. [Here](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/slip+of+paper) is a link to a thesaurus.